# bind list to sqlalchemy query python mysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pymysql

How can I bind a list to an SQL alchemy query?
The below methods do not work.

1. `engine.execute("DELETE FROM testing WHERE test_id IN %s", [1,2,3])`
2. `engine.execute("DELETE FROM testing WHERE test_id IN %s", tuple([1,2,3]))`
3. `engine.execute("DELETE FROM testing WHERE test_id IN (%s)", [1,2,3])`

They all give me error: `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the list to the query by converting it to a tuple:

```
engine.execute("DELETE FROM testing WHERE test_id in %(ids)s, ids=tuple([1,2,3])))
```